# filter dataframe with different masks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have 2 dataframe that are filtered

```
df_pass = total_avg[total_avg>3] produces the following dataframe
    AAPL        GOOGL  GOOG     MSFT 
1   3.401017    NaN     NaN     3.255119
2   NaN         NaN     NaN      NaN
3   4.16666     NaN     NaN     3.264101
4   3.049794    4.331   NaN     NaN
```

I have another filter on another DF but the layout of the DF is identical to the first on.  So this code produces the follow DF results

```
df_min_pass = total_min[total_min>-10]  
    AAPL    GOOGL   GOOG    MSFT
1   NaN      NaN   -2.099   NaN
2   NaN      NaN   -6.08    NaN
3   NaN    -8.319  -1.86    -7.3
4   NaN    -7.304  -6.92    NaN
```

Keep in mind this is just a sample of the DFs.  They have many more columns.  I want to get a resulting dataframe that combines the do.  So if it passed both condition it would give show a result in another DF otherwise show NaN if it did not meet bother conditions.  I have tried a number of combinations such as

```
df_combo_all = (df_pass[df_pass >3]) & (df_min_pass[df_min_pass >-10])
df_combo_all = df_combo_all[(df_pass[df_pass >3]) & (df_min_pass[df_min_pass >-10])]
```

Individually the filters work but I keep getting this error

TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.

There seems to be multi mask questions and others on bitwise errors but I cant seem to find one that works for me.  Can anyone please help

Comment: How to you combine they when a cell is filled in both df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update: Let's use `mask`

```
df_pass.mask(df_min_pass.isnull())
```

Output:

```
   AAPL  GOOGL  GOOG      MSFT
1   NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
2   NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
3   NaN    NaN   NaN  3.264101
4   NaN  4.331   NaN       NaN
```

Comment: yes my quesitons wasn't expplicit to what I wanted the results to be.  I do  NOT want a combined dataframe.  I want to to return the the results from df_pass only if it there was a value in df_pass and corresponding value in df_min_pass.  So the resulting dataframe should look like this where you only get 2 values (ie where the condition passed both criteria

` AAPL GOOGL GOOG  MSFT 
1 NaN          NaN           NaN
2 NaN  NaN                   NaN
3                              3.26
4 NaN         4.33                  NaN`

Comment: sorry I dont know how to add code in a comment but the only criteria that pass are MSFT in line 3 (last value) and GOOGL in line 4 (second value).  I would want to the value fro the df_pass dataframe to @Tai comment

Comment: @JWestwood Would you modify your question with your expected results.  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  ty